# Website Validation with php not working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am having trouble trying too check theses two inputs uname and passwod. I can get one to work on its own but I keep getting an error when I try to pass them both back up.

```
<?php 
// define variables and set to empty values
$usernameErr="";
$passwordErr="";
$username= "";
$password="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

    if (empty($_POST["uname"]))
        {
         $usernameErr = " username is required <br>";
         print $usernameErr;
        }

    else
        {
        $username = checkUserData($username);
        }   


    if (empty($_POST["passwd"]))
        {
         $passwordErr = "  password is required <br>";
         print $passwordErr;
        }

    else
        {
        $password = checkUserData($password);
        }   
    }
```

Here is were the problem is. I am passing down to check the data to stop attacks. I have tried multiple ways of joining them together but everything has failed.

```
function checkUserData($username)
{
    $username = htmlspecialchars($username);
    $username = trim($username);
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    return $username;
}

function checkUserData($password)
{
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
    $password = trim($password);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    return $password;
}
```

I'm printing just to check it's working.

```
print ("welcome " .checkUserData($_POST["uname"]));
print ("welcome " .checkUserData($_POST["passwd"]));
?>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: You do realise that you have 2 identical functions with the same name.... Try removing one of them.

Comment: And in both the `else` cases you are using variables which are `empty`;

Answer (score 0):

Both functions are doing the same thing so generalise them

```
function SanitizeData($var)
{
    $var= htmlspecialchars($var);
    $var= trim($var);
    $var= stripslashes($var);
    return $var;
}
```

Now in your checking process call

```
$username = SanitizeData($_POST["uname"]);
```

Or

```
$password = SanitizeData($_POST["passwd"]);
```

> Although this sanitization is unnecessary at best and destructive at worst  if you are going to use these fields in a query, it would be better to use a parameterized query and the PDO database extension.